# making minimum SQL queries to get related objects

Tags: sql, database, django

I have a method defined as follows:

```
def get_featured_books(cats=0):

"""  
This method would return a list of featured books
"""

fbooks = list()
categories = models.Category.objects.annotate( bookcount=Count('book')).order_by('bookcount')[:cats].reverse()    
for item in categories:
    fbooks.append(item.book_set.latest('posted_date'))
return fbooks
```

I use the above method on the homepage view to display a list of featured books. In the template i use the following tags:

```
{% for book in featured %}
    <h2>{{ book.title }}({{ book.category}})</h2>
    <span class="authors">{{book.authors.all|join:','}}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

But this whole concept make a lot of queries. For example if i want to display 10 featured books:

```
categories = models.Category.objects.annotate( bookcount=Count('book')).order_by('bookcount')[:cats].reverse()
```

will make one query.

```
for item in categories:
        fbooks.append(item.book_set.latest('posted_date'))
```

will make 10 queries.

and in the template `{{ book.category}}` and `{{ book.authors.all }}` will make 1 query each for each book so in my scenario the above two tags will make 20 queries. Which makes it a total of 30 queries *(Just to show a list of 10 records)*. Of course there is other stuff that i will be showing on the homepage which will make additional queries.

the question is how can i make a lesser (minimum) no. of queries to get the above information. What is the ususal practice ?

*(PS: I am aware about caching and i know the information can be cached, but my aim here is to learn about making efficient queries.)*

#### Update:

As [KrzysiekSzularz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085511/krzysiek-szularz) suggested i tried using `select_related` and `prefetch_related` as follows, but django debug toolbar still shows that it makes 32 queries.

```
def get_featured_books(cats=0):

"""  
This method would return a list of featured books
"""

fbooks = list()
categories = models.Category.objects.select_related().annotate( bookcount=Count('book')).order_by('bookcount')[:cats].reverse()    
for item in categories:
    fbooks.append(item.book_set.prefetch_related('category').latest('posted_date'))
return fbooks
```

Comment: Use `select_related` for `category` and `prefetch_related` for `authors` and `book_set`. You will end up with 3 queries.

Comment: @KrzysiekSzularz , thanks for your response. I did change to use `select_related` and `prefetch_related` but DJDT still show 32 queries , any idea why ?

Comment: You can not perform any modification to a query after `prefetch_related` has been applied. Any operation that copy existing query object would break prefetch.

Answer (score 0):

Best method to minimize the number of queries is to create SQL statements yourself and execute them the old fashioned way using SQLCommand and SQLDataAdapter. This way you can stack all of your data into one query that returns multiple tables you can use for different views.

Even better - create one stored procedure that will return all needed data. SQL Server can optimize/save execution plans for stored procedures making them even more efficient.

If you really want to stick to LINQ then this probably won't help much unfortunately.

Comment: LINQ? SQL Server? Does @Amyth even mention MS tools? Btw. you should let db optimise every query for you. Using stored procedures is just an ugly hack.